# Django - How to annotate with count of related model items

Tags: django, django-models

I have these models:

```py
class Gym(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class Employee(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  gym = models.ForeignKey(Gym)

class Appointment(models.Model):
  time = models.DateTimeField()
  gym = models.ForeignKey(Gym)

class AppointmentItem(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
  appointment = models.ForeignKey(Appointment)
```

I want to get a list of salon employees by appointment item count and filter them by appointment time.

For example something like this:

```py
Employee.objects
    .filter(gym_id=1, appointment__time__gte='2022-07-10')
    .annotate(item_count=Count('appointment_items'))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: can you discribe better what you what?

Comment: @EduardoAlejandroLeyva I will update now.

Answer (score 0):

@Chalist few thinks:

First:

```
class AppointmentItem:
```

is not declared as a model, not sure if was a typo on the question but in any case the names of the field are wrong. `appointment_item` should be `appointmentitem` and the filter should be `appointmentitem__appointment__time__gte` since you are looking for the time of the `appointment` for that `appointmentitem`.

```
Employee.objects
   .filter(gym_id=1,appointmentitem__appointment__time__gte='2020-07-01')
   .annotate(item_count=Count('appointmentitems'))
```